# Controlling Commit and Rollback in sqlrpgle

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Hi can some one tell me how to control the commit and rollback in a SQLRPGLE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by control...

There's the [COMMIT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-commit) and [ROLLBACK](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-rollback) statements

```
if someerror;
  exec SQL rollback;
else;
  exec SQL commit;
endif;
```

You can control the level of commitment control used by default for the entire module via

- a parameter on the [Create SQL ILE RPG Object (CRTSQLRPGI)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/crtsqlrpgi.htm) command
  `CRTSQLRPGI xxxx  COMMIT(*CHG)`
- using an SQL [SET OPTION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-set-option)
  `exec SQL set option commit=*CHG;`

Note that there can be only one `SET OPTION` in the module and it must physically be the first SQL statement see in the source file.

Lastly, for any given SQL statement, you can override the default commitment level by using the `WITH <xxx>` [isolation–clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statement-isolation-clause).

```
insert into mytable (fld1, fld2) 
  values ("Hello", "World")
with CHG;
```